# Does checking the truthiness of a method also run it in a conditional statement (if)?

Tags: ruby, methods

```
  def add
    puts "\nAdd a restaurant\n\n".upcase
    restaurant = Restaurant.new

    print "Restaurant name: "
    restaurant.name = gets.chomp.strip

    if restaurant.save
      puts "\nRestaurant Added\n\n"
    else
      puts "\nSave Error: Restaurant not added\n\n"
    end
  end

  def save
    return false unless Restaurant.file_usable?
    File.open(@@filepath, 'a') do |file|
      file.puts "#{[@name, @cuisine, @price].join("\t")}\n"
    end
    return true
  end
```

I am learning from a tutorial how to code in Ruby. The method `add` creates a new instance, then saves it to a file (using method `save`). In the conditional `if`, I am curious to see how `save` was invoked, considering that it was never directly called.

I know when you put a method within the if conditional and don't use any operators (i.e.: =,==,etc.) you are checking for the "truthiness" of the return value of that statement. But does putting a method in a conditional also run it? If not, how does the method `save` get called for the above example?

Comment: How would the `if` statement be evaluate the truthiness of its condition if the method wasn't called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, that method is called, executed and its return value is used as your if condition.

Just to recap: only `nil` and `false` are falsey value, any other value is considered `truthy`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you sometimes need to evaluate the truthiness of a method that would raise an exception with a nil parameter.
One possibility to avoid the exception is :

```
if !parameter.nil? && method_which_needs_a_non_nil_parameter(parameter) then
  do_something
end
```

In this case, and if parameter is nil, `method_which_needs_a_non_nil_parameter` wouldn't be called at all.